# How to get list from nested list with highest length?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below is my class structure:

```
 public class TopLevel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ChildLevelList> ChildLevelList { get; set; }
    }

public class ChildLevelList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ChildLevelList1> ChildLevelList1 { get; set; }
    }

public class ChildLevelList1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i am trying to get that ChildLevelList1 whose length is highest among all other ChildLevelList1 for each TopLevel records.If found then return that list of ChildListLevel1 for that Top level record

**For eg:** suppose i have records like below:

```
TopLevel[0]: ChildLevelList1 (Length =3)
TopLevel[1]: ChildLevelList1 (Length =4)
TopLevel[2]: ChildLevelList1 (Length =8) //get this list
TopLevel[3]: ChildLevelList1 (Length =2)
```

So I would like to get ChildLevelList for TopLevel 2 i.e from third position like below:

```
Output:[2]: ChildLevelList1 (Length =8)
```

I am trying to get in below variable:

```
var childLevelList1 // trying to get in this varaible
```

This is how I am trying:

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count(); i++)
        {
           //Sorry  but not getting how to do this.    
        }
```

Comment: `var childLevelList1 = TopLevels.Select(tl => tl.ChildLevelList)).OrderByDescending(list => list.Count).First()`

Comment: @Learning - to be honest... what you have tried  isn't  really try..Next time please provide a try that has more to it..

Comment: @GiladGreen Ok i agree with you but i was little bit stuck with the logic and i am not good with linq so i asked here.I was thinking like taking 2 index i.e 1 for the parent index and 1 for the child index and then looping and comparing but that was way too complex

Comment: @Learning - starting with a non linq solution is a good way to start :) from there you can look for questions about the different sections you have within that

Comment: @GiladGreen Can you give me any idea with out non linq solution for a start??

Comment: Learning - I can... but Tim already gave a good solution in his comment

Comment: @GiladGreen:Sorry but tim solution is not working because he is performing orderbydescending on ChildLevelList so i am still not getting ChildLevelList1 with maximum length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I choose some better names to avoid confusion

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChildLevel> ChildLevelList { get; set; }
}

public class ChildLevel // was ChildLevelList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ChildLevel1> ChildLevelList1 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildLevel1 // was ChildLevel1List
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And to get the List with the highest length

```
public List<ChildLevel1> GetBiggestChildLevel1List( IEnumerable<TopLevel> source )
{
    return source
        .SelectMany( t => t.ChildLevelList )   // IEnumerable<ChildLevel>
        .Select( c1 => c1.ChildLevelList1 )    // IEnumerable<List<ChildLevel1>>
        .OrderByDescending( c2l => c2l.Count ) // IEnumerable<List<ChildLevel1>>
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this:)

Answer (score 1):

You are going down two levels from `TopLevel`, therefore you can try with the following LINQ query:

```
var result = List.OrderByDescending(x => x.ChildLevelList.Select(y => y.ChildLevelList1.Count())).First();
```

Comment: You return the TopLevel item and not the List which was asked here

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this:)